# Centralizer in $O_{2}(R)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the order of the centralizer of any reflection group $O_{2}(R)$. What are the elements it is composed?

We have an orthogonal group of degree $2$ over $R$. What is the order and structure of centralizer of subset which is any reflection from $O(2,R)$?
As far as I know, orthogonal group over a finite group is a group for each element in is true that $AA^T=E$.

Comment: The order of the centralizer of a *given element* in $O_2(R)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1)$ $$ A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}a &b\\c &d\end{array}\right). $$
$2)$ $$ A^T=\left(\begin{array}{cc}a &c\\b &d\end{array}\right). $$
$3)$ $$ AA^T=\left(\begin{array}{cc}a^2+b^2 &ac+bd\\ac+bd &c^2+d^2\end{array}\right)=E=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 &0\\0 &1\end{array}\right). $$
It means, that:

$a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=1$

$ac+bd=0$

$4)$ $detA=\pm 1$ $\Rightarrow$ $ad-bc=\pm 1$

$5)$ From $1) - 4)$ we find general view matrix:

$$ \left(\begin{array}{cc}cos \alpha &sin \alpha\\sin \alpha &-cos \alpha\end{array}\right). $$

$6)$  Consider the particular case.

$$ A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 &0\\0 &-1\end{array}\right). $$

The centralizer is:

$Cent A$ = $<\pm \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 &0\\0 &1\end{array}\right) , \pm \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 &0\\0 &-1\end{array}\right) >$.